# React/Redux Component not re-rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, state

I am having a problem with a react component not re-rendering even though I see the state being properly updated. I am using redux, I have read state mutation is often the issue/cause of this I just dont think I am doing that. The value I am updating is nested 3 levels deep within the state.

Here is the code:

```
import { RECEIVE_CURRENT_SCAN_RESULT } from '../constants';

const initialState = {
    currentScanResult: {info:{}, results:[]},
};

[RECEIVE_CURRENT_SCAN_RESULT]: (state, payload) =>
    Object.assign({}, state, {
      currentScanResult: Object.assign(state.currentScanResult, payload)
    }),

export function createReducer(initialState, reducerMap) {
    return (state = initialState, action) => {
        const reducer = reducerMap[action.type];

        return reducer
            ? reducer(state, action.payload)
            : state;
    }
}
```

Comment: Posted an answer with a suggested solotion, plus suggested  a very small edit to your question (Stackoverflow needs the 'javascript' tag on the question or else the syntax high-lighting doesn't work, which is why your code, and any code in a posted answer, just looks like grey text with no color.).

Comment: PS. I just added a clarification to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) the first argument is the "target" object,

so this line

```
currentScanResult: Object.assign(state.currentScanResult, payload)
```

is still mutating the `currentScanResult` property on the state.

Use an empty object as first argument in `Object.assign`, like you did on the first level, so the whole thing becomes:

```
// empty object as target here
Object.assign({}, state, {
  // empty object as target here as well
  currentScanResult: Object.assign({}, state.currentScanResult, payload)
})
```

and that should at least test if the the problem is a problem of mutation or if there is something else that needs fixing.

Comment: Good to hear it works!  You don't suck! Learning is hard sometimes (if it was easy then Stackoverflow wouldn't exist), and even after you learn something well, it's easy to make small mistakes like that.